# Some way for allocating and initializing array faster than plain loop-and-set

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is how I allocate and initialize an array in C++.

```
char *dataPtr;

dataPtr= new char [40000]; 

int i; 

for(i=0;i<40000;i++)

{
    dataPtr[i]=200; 
}
```

Is there any other faster and cleaner way of achieving this as the for loop is taking considerable time for my application?

Comment: I legitimately doubt this loop is taking any time on your application.

Comment: I completely agree with Rapptz. Maybe if you have optimizations off. Anyways, fill_n or memset might buy you some extra time if you have some luck, but most probably you are trying to fix something that's not broken, or at least, you're looking at wrong thing or you're not measuring the time correctly

Answer (score 4):

Use an `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> data(40000, 200);
```

Comment: may be I am doing something wrong , but I am getting this error: Error 2 error C2040: 'dataPtr' : 'std::vector<_Ty>' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'

Comment: I just added these two lines to my code: char *dataPtr; std::vector<char> dataPtr(40000, 200);

Comment: @user2799508 Just `#include <vector>` and `std::vector<char> dataPtr(40000, 200);`

Comment: @user: You don't need to add the first line you quoted, `char*dataPtr`. The vector-line can handle it by itself. Use **either** an array, **or** a vector. Consider the vector to be a super array on steroids.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `memset()`, which has a core of optimized assembly with SSE/SSE2/etc instructions as appropriate at runtime.  The `memset()` function is designed to do exactly this task: set each `char` in an array of `char` to a specific value, as quickly as possible.

```
#include <cstring>

char *dataPtr = new char[LENGTH];
std::memset(dataPtr, 200, LENGTH);
```

However, modern compilers will do this for you, you can check the assembly, and you might find a call to `memset()` or something similar in the original code that used a `for` loop.  It's only 40 kB anyway, so you're not going to save much time, unless you have to initialize the array very often.

Comment: @haccks: I fail to see the relevance of that link... could you explain?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: The C++ standard defines a `char` to be one byte... no matter how wide it is.  So the guarantee is there, but the definition of "byte" is not the one you are used to.

Comment: ouch, you're right. That's byte that's of undefined width, not char, I often mistake them when writing in haste.

Answer (score 3):

To initialize each array elements by `200` you can use

```
std::fill_n(dataPtr, 40000, 200);
```

Comment: FWIW, `std::fill_n` will be not any _fast_, it uses loop too

Comment: @P0W: That depends on the compiler. I know MSVC++ will use `memset()` if the parameters to `std::fill` or `std::fill_n` are pointers to `char`.